# Compilation errors when drawing a piechart using d3.js and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, typescript

I am attempting to draw a pie chart using the d3.js library and TypeScript. I have the following code:

```
"use strict";
module Chart {
  export class chart {

    private chart: d3.Selection<string>;
    private width: number;
    private height: number;
    private radius: number;
    private donutWidth: number;
    private dataset: { label: string, count: number }[];
    private color: d3.scale.Ordinal<string, string>;

    constructor(container: any) {
      this.width = 360;
      this.height = 360;
      this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;
      this.donutWidth = 75;

      this.dataset = [
        { label: 'Road', count: 5500 },
        { label: 'Bridge', count: 8800 },
        { label: 'Tunnel', count: 225 },
      ];

      this.color = d3.scale.category10();

      this.init(container);

    }

    private init(container) {
      this.chart = d3.select(container).append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (this.width / 2) +
        ',' + (this.height / 2) + ')');
    }

    draw() {

      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(this.radius - this.donutWidth)  // NEW
        .outerRadius(this.radius);

      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null);

      var path = this.chart.selectAll('path')
        .data(pie(this.dataset.map(function(n) {
          return n.count;
        })))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
          return Math.random();
        });
    }

  }
}
```

The code  does not compile with the error:

```
 Argument of type 'Arc<Arc>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(datum: Arc<number>, index: number, outerIndex: number) => string | number | boolean'.
>>   Types of parameters 'd' and 'datum' are incompatible.
>>     Type 'Arc' is not assignable to type 'Arc<number>'.
>>       Property 'value' is missing in type 'Arc'.
```

The compilation error is showing up when I try to add the `d` attribute to each of the `path` elements on my svg:

```
var path = this.chart.selectAll('path')
        .data(pie(this.dataset.map(function(n) {
          return n.count;
        })))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
          return Math.random();
        });
```

According to the documentation an arc is "is both an object and a function." and I see that I can access it by calling `arc(datum[, index])`, by just hardcoding `arc[0]` for example. When I do this my compilation error goes away but the `d` attribute of each `path` element in the svg is missing and I end up with an svg like:

```
    <svg height="360" width="360">
      <g transform="translate(180,180)">
         <path fill="0.35327279710072423"></path>
         <path fill="0.6333000506884181"></path>
         <path fill="0.9358429045830001"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I've had the code running as pure JavaScript with no problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Came here because I had the same problem with D3 v5!

Solution: Use the `PieArcDatum` interface (Very strange name in my opinion!!!)

Details:

```js
import { PieArcDatum } from 'd3-shape';

... 

type Population = { time: string, population: number; };

...

const svg = element.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${300}, ${160})`)
;

const pie = d3.pie<Population>()
    .sort(null)
    .value((record) => record.population);

const path = d3.arc<PieArcDatum<Population>>()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(150)
;

// Beim selectAll kommt eine leere Selection zurück da es noch keinen Circle gibt
const data = pie(worldPopulation);
const arch = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc")
;

arch.append('path')
    .attr("d", path)
;
```

Sidenote: I'm using WebStorm, WS was not able to find (autoimport) PieArcDatum - I had to import it manually...

Comment: @MattWattson: This should be the accepted answer as it solves the problem correctly, not just cast it away.

Answer (score 17):

Try to replace

```
.attr('d', arc)
```

with

```
.attr('d', <any>arc)
```

This hides the compiler error on my computer but if that actually work... Well, I don't know.

My understanding of the problem is that you provide `.data` function with `number` values and TypeScript compiler expects that `.attr` will contain also a number but you provide an `arc` instead.

Comment: That worked.  This is the first time I've seen the `<any>` syntax, will need to investigate that further

Comment: You can search `TypeScript casting` with Google. Note that it is compile-time casting.

Comment: `any` tells the compiler not to check. You will want to type this correctly if possible

Answer (score 8):

While using `<any>` will work to avoid compilation errors, it defeats the purpose of having type checking in the first place. After much trial and error and quality time with [the `d3.d.ts` definition for the Arc layout](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts#L2376), I figured out how to make the types line up:

```
function draw() {

    let arc = d3.svg.arc<d3.layout.pie.Arc<number>>()
        .innerRadius(this.radius - this.donutWidth)
        .outerRadius(this.radius);

    let pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);

    let tfx = (d: d3.layout.pie.Arc<number>): string => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)})`);

    // create a group for the pie chart
    let g = this.chart.selectAll('g')
        .data(pie(this.dataset.map(n => n.count)))
        .enter().append('g');

    // add pie sections
    g.append('path').attr('d', arc);

    // add labels
    g.append('text').attr('transform', tfx).text(d => d.data.label);
}
```

In addition to the original question, I've also shown how to add labels to a pie chart and maintain the strong typing of Typescript. Note that this implementation takes advantage of [the alternate constructor `d3.svg.arc<T>(): Arc<T>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts#L2377) that allows you to specify a type for the `arc` sections.

### Update

The above code assumes that the `data` being passed is an array of numbers. If you look at the code though (in particular the accessors `n => n.count` and `d => d.data.label`), it is clearly not. Those accessors also have an implicit `any` type, i.e. `(n: any) => n.count`. This could possibly throw a runtime error if the `n` happens to be an object without a `count` property. Here's a rewrite that makes the shape of the `data` more explicit:

```
interface Datum {
    label: string;
    count: number;
}

function draw() {

    // specify Datum as shape of data
    let arc = d3.svg.arc<d3.layout.pie.Arc<Datum>>()
        .innerRadius(this.radius - this.donutWidth)
        .outerRadius(this.radius);

    // notice accessor receives d of type Datum
    let pie = d3.layout.pie<Datum>().sort(null).value((d: Datum):number => d.count);

    // note input to all .attr() and .text() functions
    // will be of type d3.layout.pie.Arc<Datum>
    let tfx  = (d: d3.layout.pie.Arc<Datum>): string => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)})`;
    let text = (d: d3.layout.pie.Arc<Datum>): string => d.data.category;

    // create a group for the pie chart
    let g = this.chart.selectAll('g')
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append('g');

    // add pie sections
    g.append('path').attr('d', arc);

    // add labels
    g.append('text').attr('transform', tfx).text(text);
}
```

In this second version, there are no longer any implicit `any` types. Another thing to note is that the name of the interface, `Datum`, is arbitrary. You could name that interface anything you wanted to, but would just have to be careful to change all references to `Datum` to whatever more appropriate name you chose.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I don't get how var arc = d3.svg.arc() beomces = d3.svg.arc<d3.layout.pie.Arc<number>>(). It works, but what is it doing? Is it casting arc to type <d3.layout.pie.Arc<number>>, a number?

Comment: Yes, more or less. The `svg.Arc` class can create arcs out of most any kind of data. The part inside the inner angle brackets specifies the shape of the data being represented in your `pie.Arc`. If your data is just an array of numbers then `<number>` will work. If it's more complicated then you will want to define a class like`Datum` to represent the shape of your data and use that.